# CASE expression within Window Function in SQL (ANSII)

Tags: sql, case, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, window-functions

I'm using SQL to try and replicate a table which has time frames as rows, and days of the week as fields.

To do this I have attempted to nest a case statement within a window function, but I can't quite get the syntax right (or for all I know it's not actually possible). The code is below:

```
select

sum(case when DAYNAME(i.date_key) = 'Mon' then(i.price) 

over(

partition by 

                case when(t.transaction_time) between '06:00:00' and '08:59:59' then '06:00 - 09:00' else
                case when(t.transaction_time) between '09:00:00' and '11:59:59' then '09:00 - 12:00' else
                case when(t.transaction_time) between '12:00:00' and '14:59:59' then '12:00 - 15:00' else
                case when(t.transaction_time) between '15:00:00' and '17:59:59' then '15:00 - 18:00' else
                case when(t.transaction_time) between '18:00:00' and '20:59:59' then '18:00 - 21:00')   as Mon

from 
MainSales i
inner join Transactions t on i.transaction_key = t.transaction_key
where i.date_key between '2020-01-01' and '2021-01-01'
```

Any help or pointers would be much appreciated. This bit of code would then be replicated for the remaining days of the week.

Thanks!

Comment: Please explain what system you are using that supports "ANSI SQL".  And, for the record, the code you have shown is not standard-compliant.

Comment: Missing `end)` at the end of line 2. You could just `where dayname() = 'Mon'` instead of conditional `sum(case...)`

Comment: Have one `case` _expression_, with several `when` clauses, and don't forget the `end`.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Apologies, I've noticed some errors in this - I'll amend, delete and re-post (if that's the correct way to do it)

Thanks for all the responses so far. I'm using the Snowflake platform

Comment: We are happy to help you, but please make sure to show us some sample data and desired results.